# Manipulate height of cells on google document using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to draw a table on Google Document using `Google Apps Script` then convert the result to `PDF`. That works fine but I couldn't *manipulate a height of cells*. 
Here is my code :

```
var TemplateCopyBody = DocumentApp.openById("id").getActiveSection();
var tableStyle = {};
tableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 8;
tableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] =  DocumentApp.FontFamily.UBUNTU;
tableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = 0;
tableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = 0;
tableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_RIGHT] = 0;
tableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEIGHT] = 0;


/* Function to populate my table */
var myTable = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<RESULT.marksDetails.length -1;i++){
  myTable[i] = RESULT.notesDetails[i];
  Logger.log("insertion table : "+i);
}


TemplateCopyBody.appendTable(myTable).setAttributes(tableStyle).setColumnWidth(0, 300);
```

I really need your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the height of every other row to 45 pixels, and the others to 22 pixels, I would have done something like this:

```
var newTable = TemplateCopyBody.appendTable(myTable);
  for(var i=1; i < myTable.length ;i++){
    if(i % 2 == 0)
      newTable.getRow(i).setMinimumHeight(22);
    else
      newTable.getRow(i).setMinimumHeight(45);
  }
  newTable.setAttributes(tableStyle).setColumnWidth(0, 300);
```